# How to get all of existing requests in Volley?

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

I' m using Volley library to implement networking in my android application. I want to get all of existing requests in my 'RequestQueue' object. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request queue from volley, firstly you must add all your request in asingle queue.

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

Comment: I want to get my request in RequestQueue, not to get 'RequestQueue' object.